# How to render an option at the last position in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown-menu

[image]

---

```
<select id="assignment-type-dd">
    <option value="all">Assignment Type: All</option>
    <option value="section exercises">section exercises</option>
    <option value="course benchmark">course benchmark</option>
    <option value="chapter quiz">chapter quiz</option>
    <option value="chapter test">chapter test</option>
</select>
```

---

I generate the select above using Javascript.

```
$.each(responseData, function(i, v) {

  var assessmentType = v.assessmentType;
  var sameAssignmentType = $('#assignment-type-dd option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == assessmentType;
  })

  if(!sameAssignmentType.length){
    //if assessmentType === Course Benchmark append it as last option
    $('#assignment-type-dd').append('<option value="' + assessmentType + '">' + assessmentType + '</option>');
  }

});
```

---

This is what I'm trying to produce using my JS

```
<select id="assignment-type-dd">
    <option value="all">Assignment Type: All</option>
    <option value="section exercises">section exercises</option>
    <option value="chapter quiz">chapter quiz</option>
    <option value="chapter test">chapter test</option>
    <option value="course benchmark">course benchmark</option>
</select>
```

__
What is most efficient way to do something like that ?

Comment: In your current code, each incoming item will scan the whole option list, you can use an `object` to store existing options first, and only append the not exist ones.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thanks for you the hint.